# changing jdk used for compilation - environment variables

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have  3 different JDK installed on my computer,
what environment-variable should I set to make javac  use jdk  1.5, 
if I type   java  -version, it gives 1.7

please, clarify me a bit, how do those correlate, e.g
if java -version  says  1.7, does it mean that javac is going to use java 1.5,
and which variable should I change to make things different

UPDATE:
I want to change the behaviour of javac, 
how do I make  javac to call 1.5 compiler? WITHOUT ANY keys added, I need it to be default, what variables do I need to change

WINDOWS

Answer (score 1):

if you are in *unix system, just found which javac you use:

`which javac`

and which java you use:

`which java`

if you use a `JAVA_HOME` in your path, just put the `JAVA_HONE/bin` at the beginning of the `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is part of the JDK, you have to call the appropriate compiler for the JDK version you want to use.

For example if you have:

/jdk1
/jdk2
/jdk3

then you would need to reference the javac compiler in the bin folder of the appropriate JDK, e.g. . /jdk2/bin/javac.

You are likely just typing javac and therefore calling whichever is on the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your 7 compiler with different compile options to compile into previous versions. Try

```
javac -source 1.5 <source>
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#options)

Comment: To be clear, this will produce code compatible for running on a v5 jre, not call the v5 compiler.